# Clearinterval when user is searching

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have this form which
i use to search some records in the database.

It's inside a page named: listaupdate.php

I have another lista.php which i use it in order to refresh and get updates of listaupdate.php

Now, with the help of some people here i got to this part:
listaupdate.php

```
<form action="listasearch.php" method="post">
<select name="kategoria">
<option value="status">Status</option>
</select> 
<input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

The form, and in lista.php i have:

```
 var interval = setInterval(function(){
$('#lista').show().load('listaupdate.php').fadeIn("slow");}, 3000);
$('input[name="search"]').on("focus", function(event){
     interval = clearInterval(interval);
});

// restart it when search is done
$("form").submit( function(event){
         interval = setInterval(function(){
        $('#lista').show().load('listaupdate.php').fadeIn("slow");}, 3000);
  });
```

What i need is that, when someone is searching the reload should stop. Then after the form restet it should start again..

Thanks

Comment: why do you need to refresh? is the data real-time?

Comment: yes, the data is real time.. that's why!

Answer (score 0):

Is the

```
$('input[name="search"]').on("focus", function(event){
     interval = clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Is in the interval?
Remove from it and change it like this:

```
$('input[name="search"]').on("focus", function(event){
     clearInterval(interval);
     interval = 0;
});
```

Comment: Is the interval is running after the focus is on the search input?

You should try to add an alert to the focus,to check is it really called or not.

Try to change .on("focus") to .focus